# How do I get the exact time for status field in Docker?

Tags: docker

How do I get the exact exit time (Status field) in Docker ?

I can only get "Exited (0) 3 days ago"

I know I can get the exact creation time with this command:

```
docker ps --format 'table {{.ID}}\t{{.Command}}\t{{.CreatedAt}}'
```

But if I change it to:

```
docker ps --format 'table {{.ID}}\t{{.Command}}\t{{.CreatedAt}}\t{{.Status}}'
```

the status is not in exact format it's shows "Exited (0) 3 days ago" again.

Is there any field with the exact time ? I also couldn't find a reference table to all fields. Where is it ?